# Counting occurrence of values after using groupby on multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, frequency

My input dataframe is as follows :

[image: Input data]

generated using the following lines of code

```
 l = [["a", 12, 12], ["a", 12, 33.], ["b", 12.3, 12.3], ["a", 13, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["a", "b", "c"])
```

I am currently able to cumulatively count the frequency as follows

[image: Output]

using

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby(by=["a","b"]).cumcount()+1
```

which takes into account common values in column a and column b and counts them. However I would like to add to the freq count only when column b values are different while column a values are the same. The picture below shows a form of desired output :

[image: Desired output]

How do I achieve this in pandas in an optimised manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use double `.groupby`. For example:

```py
df["freq"] = df.groupby("a")["b"].apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x).ngroup() + 1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   a     b     c  freq
0  a  12.0  12.0     1
1  a  12.0  33.0     1
2  b  12.3  12.3     1
3  a  13.0   1.0     2
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, try:

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0] + 1)
```

Output:

```
   a     b     c  freq
0  a  12.0  12.0     1
1  a  12.0  33.0     1
2  b  12.3  12.3     1
3  a  13.0   1.0     2
```

[`pd.Series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html#pandas-series-factorize) will create a int per unique value of 'b' stating with zero.

Comment: Thank you. Always learning through the awesome community on stackoverflow, I would have never thought of solving it this way.

Comment: @CC_ You're welcome.  Happy coding. Be safe and stay healthy.