# Add a column to reflect the amount that a value has occurred in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":['a','a','a','b','b','c'],
                   "Year":[2019, 2020, 2021, 2015, 2019, 2011]})
print(df)
```

```
  Name  Year
0    a  2019
1    a  2020
2    a  2021
3    b  2015
4    b  2019
5    c  2011
```

I want to add a column such that reflects the number of times a name has appeared. For example, when 'a' appears in the first row, the "Occurrences" column will have a '1'. When 'a' appears again (the data is sorted), the "Occurrences" column will have a '2', and so on:

```
  Name  Year  Occurrences
0    a  2019            1
1    a  2020            2
2    a  2021            3
3    b  2015            1
4    b  2019            2
5    c  2011            1
```

I have thought about using some sort of for loop to do this, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach using [`pandas.GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to group `Name` and return sequence number of each element within each group.

```py
df['Occurrences'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount() + 1 
print(df)
```

---

```
  Name  Year  Occurrences
0    a  2019            1
1    a  2020            2
2    a  2021            3
3    b  2015            1
4    b  2019            2
5    c  2011            1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar post, and you can check this answer [@Andrej Kesely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911751/counting-occurrence-of-values-after-using-groupby-on-multiple-pandas-columns):

```py
df["Occurrences"] = df.groupby("Name")["Year"].apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x).ngroup() + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the following code:

```py
df['Occurances'] = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Year']).groupby('Name').cumcount() + 1
```

It works as follows:

1. Use [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to order the rows by `Name` followed by `Year` (so that it works even when the rows are unsorted).
2. Use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the rows by `Name`.
3. Use [`.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to compute a running total for the number of rows in each of these groups, outputted as a single Series.

   (Each running total will start from 0, so add 1 to the result to get the true count).
4. Assign the result to a new column called `Occurances`.

---

#### Testing for unsorted DataFrame

Input data (unsorted):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Name': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'],
    'Year': [2020, 2019, 2015, 2021, 2011, 2019]
}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
print(df)
```

```
  Name  Year
0    a  2020
1    a  2019
2    b  2015
3    a  2021
4    c  2011
5    b  2019
```

Creating the `Occurances` column:

```
df['Occurances'] = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Year']).groupby('Name').cumcount() + 1

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Year  Occurances
0    a  2020           2
1    a  2019           1
2    b  2015           1
3    a  2021           3
4    c  2011           1
5    b  2019           2
```

Sorted output:

```py
df_sorted = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Year'], ignore_index=True)

print(df_sorted)
```

```
  Name  Year  Occurances
0    a  2019           1
1    a  2020           2
2    a  2021           3
3    b  2015           1
4    b  2019           2
5    c  2011           1
```